# Is there a way of downloading the whole of a webpage source in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I am using a **`WebRequest()`** function within the MetaTrader Terminal 4 codebase (MQL4) that allows one to download a HTML-response from a website.

Example site: http://www.forexfactory.com/docphoenix66#acct.57-tab.list

Here is an example how it is used in the MQL4 function call:

```
res = WebRequest( "GET",
                  "http://www.forexfactory.com/docphoenix66#acct.57-tab.list",
                  cookie,
                  NULL,
                  timeout,
                  post,
                  0,
                  result,
                  headers
                  );
```

and the documentation for the function [**`WebRequest()`**](https://docs.mql4.com/common/webrequest)

However, if I compare what is downloaded using a `WebRequest()` call with what you see when you right click and inspect element using Chrome or Safari, the bits I want available are missing!

In particular I want the trade information from below the following columns:

```
Instrument      Price Open/Close        Date Open/Close     Lots        Return  
Profit      Pips        Chart       Balance     Swap        Duration
```

And if you see below an example of what is missing from the htm file downloaded using the MQL4 function.

```
<td class="slidetable__cell slidetable__cell--fixed" style="width: 62px; min-width: 62px;"> <a id="snap_48205_trade_109309333" class="explorer__anchor explorer__anchor--trade"></a>

EUR/USD

</td>
```

If you download the HTML file, turn off your wifi and then open the file to see what was downloading, you see everything in the trade explorer still loading. Am I clear on what my problem is?

Comment: IIt looks like the body of your response is returned in an array. you will need to write some looping logic to step through that array and retrieve that data in order to locate the elements you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

### Short version: Yes, there is.

---

### Long version: **`TL;DR;`**

> Well, first, **welcome to the Wild Worlds of MQL4**

Given the intention is clear and given you were "promised" that there is "*a **possible way** to read a HTML-page*", **I have to tell you it is not possible in all cases you will meet in real-world.**

One may spend ages in MQL4-code domain to re-design html-sort-of Mark-Up syntax-(b)**L**OBs, suffering from all the restricted constraints the MQL4-code execution engine provided.

Nevertheless, the much faster, joyfull and a **sure and future-proof** ( read other posts on historically painfull creeping of the language syntax relief and crippled man*decades in API-integration code-base efforts ) **approach exists** .

**Integrate** MQL4-side via a professional fast & low-latency SIG/MSG-infrastructure **with external, distributed processes**, that can provide high-performance & robust services to MetaTrader Terminal ecosystem.

Using this approach we have prototyped and operate fast Mixed-Technical-**and**-Fundamental AI/ML-Inputs, including Web-page-feeds of Fundamental Data and News Announcements into the FX-trading realm 24/7/365 and it works blessingly well, independently of the limits the common MQL4 execution has.

If still in doubts, just try to read a page on **`rss.provider.com:6322/FED_actuals`** URL via a call to **`WebReqest()`** and you know, where is the dog burried.